# mysql map comma seperated coumn values with new values by table lookup

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL database.

I have a `CUST_INV_DET` table where I have data in below format

```
---------------------------
CUSTOMER_ID   CUSTOMER_NO
---------------------------
     1        1983,1988,1989
     2        2014,2011,2010
     3        3012,3059,3045 
---------------------------
```

And there is another table. NEW_CUSTOMER_NO_FORMAT

```
--------------------------------------
OLD_CUSTOMER_NO      NEW_CUSTOMER_NO
--------------------------------------
1983                    C1983-01
1988                    C1988-03
1989                    C1989-06
2014                    C2014-01
2011                    C2011-02
2010                    C2010-02
3012                    C3012-03
3059                    C3059-23
3045                    C3045-09
```

Can anybody suggest me on how to map `CUST_INV_DET.CUSTOMER_NO` in a new format by doing lookup from `NEW_CUSTOMER_NO_FORMAT` Table.

I know I need to use cursor but inside cursor below section I am clueless how to map since it's a comma separated value.

Do I need one more cursor inside NO_MORE_DATA =0 ?

```
IF (NO_MORE_DATA = 0) THEN

  //MAP OLD TO NEW FORMAT HERE

END IF;
```

Below are the insert script

```
CREATE TABLE CUST_INV_DET(
  CUSTOMER_ID INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  CUSTOMER_NO VARCHAR(500)
);

INSERT INTO CUST_INV_DET(CUSTOMER_NO) VALUES
('1983,1988,1989'),
('2014,2011,2010'),
('3012,3059,3045');

CREATE TABLE NEW_CUSTOMER_NO_FORMAT (
  OLD_CUSTOMER_NO VARCHAR(500),
  NEW_CUSTOMER_NO VARCHAR(500)
);

INSERT INTO NEW_CUSTOMER_NO_FORMAT VALUES
('1983','C1983-01'),
('1988','C1988-03'),
('1989','C1989-06'),
('2014','C2014-01'),
('2011','C2011-02'),
('2010','C2010-02'),
('3012','C3012-03'),
('3059','C3059-23'),
('3045','C3045-09');
```

Below is the final output I am looking for

```
CUSTOMER_ID           CUSTOMER_NO                    
1                     'C1983-01,C1988-03,C1989-06'
2                     'C2014-01,C2011-02,C2010-02'
3                     'C3012-03,C3059-23,C3045-09'
```

Comment: Do you want to map multiple NEW_CUSTOMER_NO to CUSTOMER_ID? Like for Customer ID 1, you will have C1983-01,C1988-03,C1989-06. And do you want a single select query or you want to insert/update data in some other table ? Also please add table structures in question.

Comment: Congratulations. So now you know why storing CSVs is such a bad idea.

Comment: Somebody got this bad idea 10 years ago. :D

Comment: That doesn't make it any better :-(

Comment: Storing a comma-separated list as a string in a table means about "this is just a string; I don't care about its parts in my database". So don't do this in your DBMS. Don't use SQL. Use a programming language, be it PHP, Java or whatever, and read the two tables, loop and do some string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CUSTOMER_ID, 
substring(Customer_no,0,charindex(',',Customer_no,1)) col1,
substring(Customer_no,charindex(',',Customer_no,1) + 1,charindex(',',Customer_no,1)-1) col2,
substring(Customer_no,charindex(',',Customer_no,1) + len(substring(Customer_no,charindex(',',Customer_no,1) + 1,charindex(',',Customer_no,1)-1) )+2,charindex(',',Customer_no,1)-1) col3
into #Temp2
from CUST_INV_DET
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T. CUSTOMER_ID,
       NCD1.NEW_CUSTOMER_NO + ',' + NCD2.NEW_CUSTOMER_NO + ',' + NCD3.NEW_CUSTOMER_NO
FROM #Temp2 T
INNER JOIN NEW_CUSTOMER_NO_FORMAT NCD1 ON NCD1.OLD_CUSTOMER_NO = T.col1
INNER JOIN NEW_CUSTOMER_NO_FORMAT NCD2 ON NCD2.OLD_CUSTOMER_NO = T.col2
INNER JOIN NEW_CUSTOMER_NO_FORMAT NCD3 ON NCD3.OLD_CUSTOMER_NO = T.col3
```

Comment: Thanks but the no of comma seperated values are not fixed.